# Wireless M-bus / OMS packet decoding

Tags: aes

```
3E4424237952324825077A09503005702970D754206CF3FFA5A2EE90103E42049140ACA625243A7DC4550DB811208D8299D7A34EB9ECBEE9CD751A685F0FF05D1A3D004F320600211B
```

This is the packet I received from a wm-bus (OMS) water meter, it's striped of CRC bytes.

As I get it from the OMS documentation this is the CBC initial vector:

```
24237952324825070909090909090909
```

And AES password is: 1111111111111111

As I get it the first AES block that needs decoding is:

```
702970d754206cf3ffa5a2ee90103e42
```

And after decoding the first two bytes should be 2f 2f but they aren't.

Comment: Try here: https://platform.lobaro.com/#/wmbus/parser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not get `0x2F 0x2F` then the short answer is: you took the wrong aes key.

**Detail:**
You seem to take the right bytes and derived the right IV for this OMS telegram. If the first 2 bytes of the decrypted part do not result in `0x2F 0x2F` then this indicates that you have the wrong AES key for this telegram.

You say your key is 1111111111111111 - but what is this? An AES-CBC Key for OMS works with 16 bytes (128bit). You only have 16 characters, but to express 16 bytes in hex you will require 32 characters. So there is something fishy with this key:
`0x01010101010101010101010101010101` is not working.

Neither is `0x31313131313131313131313131313131` (which is 16 times 1 in ASCII)

However I was successful to decrypt with

```
0x11111111111111111111111111111111

//Decrypted telegram:
3E 44 24 23 79 52 32 48 25 07 7A 09 50 30 05 2F 2F 0C 13 00 02 00 00 02 5A F5 00 02 FD 17 00 10 02 FD 74 ED 16 C2 01 6C DF 17 CC 01 13 00 02 00 00 2F 2F 2F 2F 2F 2F 2F 2F 2F 2F 2F 2F 2F 2F
```

So in the end it looks like you just took one half of the key and that's why the decryption failed.

Comment: Yes I figured it after five days, manufacturer thing, it gives you an interface to enter 8 ascii letters, I figured that how you figured it, that either it should be 16 x 0x31 but later I figured it that that software takes the key in ascii and duplicates it, kind of dumb